# how to add html.dropdown in grid in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

```
<div style="margin-left:27px; margin-bottom:20px;">
            <h2>Email Scheduler</h2>
            <div id="dvtblCustomer" class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table-bordered col-offset-12">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="label-primary">
                            <th style="padding:5px 15px;">
                                Customer Designation
                                 @Html.DropDownList("CustomerDesignation", new SelectList(Model., "Value", "Text"), new { id = "CustomerDesignationDDL", name = "CustomerDesignationDDL" })
                            </th> 
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr style="text-align:center">
                            <td>
                                @item.CustomerDesignation
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my webgrid. I want to add dropdownlist in table header for table filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem` is an assembly class used for this purpose.

Given your `CustomerDesignation` model is a list of designations, then construct a `List<SelectListItem>` from it as below where `designations` is your database/file driven list of customer designations:

```
List<SelectListItem> designationList = designations.Select(d => new SelectListItem { 
  Text = d.CustomerDesignationDDL, 
  Value = d.CustomerDesignationDDL 
}).ToList();
```

You bind the `SelectItemList` designationList to your view model

```
Model.Designations = designationList;
```

In the view, dropdown for the same can be populated as such:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Designations, Model.Designations)
```